# Moving average for all entries less than the date in the current row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
product_type = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'prod_id':np.repeat(np.arange(start=2,stop=5,step=1),59),'prod_type': np.random.choice(np.array(product_type), 177),'sales_time': pd.date_range(start ='1-1-2018', 
         end ='3-30-2018', freq ='12H'),'sale_amt':np.random.randint(4,100,size = 177)})

df.head()

prod_id prod_type    sales_time          sale_amt
2          A         2018-01-01 00:00:00    66
2          A         2018-01-01 12:00:00    57
2          B         2018-01-02 00:00:00    19
2          A         2018-01-02 12:00:00    16
2          A         2018-01-03 00:00:00    61
```

Now what I want is to get the average of **sales_amt** grouped by ***prod_id, prod_type*** for all the transactions that happened before the current record's date, so for example the desired output would be:

```
prod_id prod_type    sales_time          sale_amt  avg_sale_amt
2          A         2018-01-01 00:00:00    66       0
2          A         2018-01-01 12:00:00    57       0
2          B         2018-01-02 00:00:00    19       0
2          A         2018-01-02 12:00:00    16       61.5
2          A         2018-01-03 00:00:00    61       46.3
```

I know how to groupby and calculate moving average and ignoring the current row:

```
sf = df.sort_values('sales_time')
sf['avg_sale_amt'] = sf.groupby(['prod_id', 'prod_type'])['sale_amt'].transform(lambda gr: gr.expanding().mean().shift())
```

but I don't know how to ignore the given date and take all records less than that date for average calculation.

Answer (score 0):

you can have the cummulative mean by taking `cumsum/cumcount`, then `shift`:

```
sf = df.sort_values('sales_time')
gb = sf.groupby(['prod_id', 'prod_type'])


sf['avg_sale_amt'] = gb['sale_amt'].cumsum()/gb['sale_amt'].cumcount().add(1)
sf['avg_sale_amt'] = gb['avg_sale_amt'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   prod_id prod_type           sales_time  sale_amt  avg_sale_amt
0        2         A  2018-01-01 00:00:00        66      0.000000
1        2         A  2018-01-01 12:00:00        57     66.000000
2        2         B  2018-01-02 00:00:00        19      0.000000
3        2         A  2018-01-02 12:00:00        16     61.500000
4        2         A  2018-01-03 00:00:00        61     46.333333
```

Comment: This solution's output does not match with the desired output, for instance if you see row 2, it contains avg_sale_amt as 66, although it should be 0 , as the entry above it, is from the same date. The moving average should only be for all entries having date less(not less than equal) than the current value of the row.

Comment: I see. You want to calculate on per-day basis, but your data is not. You can do so by aggregating your data to daily data. Then you can apply the answer here, finally merge the output with original data by `prod_id, prod_type, date`.